# Working with multiple NSTableView into NSWindowController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I am working to a window with multiples `NSTableView` (in my case 8) and I am not sure if it's correct what I do.
My screen look like printscreen : [custom window](http://imgur.com/YClSBua)

In principle my window it's a Master - Detail Interface a selection of table from the left must populate the right table. 
 Until now I succeded to populate all the tables from the left with help of `cocoa binding` - `NSArrayController` which contain custom objects but further I don't know how continue, obvious in my mind it's to implement delegate method for `NSTableView`: `tableViewSelectionDidChange:notification` but this require more glue code.

 My question if it's possible to populate the right table with help of cocoa binding without glue code. I read documention and I tried with selection proprety of `NSArrayController` but all my attempts failed. Any suggestion?

Comment: On the left, have you bound the tableView's selection indexes to the array controller key of selectionIndexes?

Comment: no, but I tried now  and I created also a proprety for this selection of type `NSIndexSet` and this appear in logs correct, but in final  looks like must write same bunch of code like in delegate method of `tableView`.

Comment: @stevesliva or it's  possible to make a settup for  right `tableView` to track selection from other tables (to populate all the tables from left I used 7 `NSArrayController`). thanks

Comment: Yes, once you have the selection bindings in place on the left, you create object/array controllers for the right, and bind the views to those controllers, and bind those controllers to the selection of the controllers for the left.

Comment: @stevesliva Thanks I found a way to make this easy.

Comment: @geo_nl, post your answer?